# How to read JSON input values into Terraform scripts?

Tags: json, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am implementing Terraform scripts for the AWS infrastructure automation, in my scenario AWS input variables like AMI-ID, KeyPairName, etc, will be passed from a JSON file, how to read those values into my Terraform vars files?

I have tried to pass the variables from the terraform.tfvars file it's working fine, in the same way, I am expecting to read JSON file values.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? And what you're specifically struggling with?

Comment: Hi @ydaetskcoR, Thanks for your response. I was trying to send input variables in a JSON file rather than in vars.tf or terraform.tfvars. But I am able to get the result by applying this command. **terraform apply --var-file=input.json**